# canvas-lms on ubuntu 20.04. Trying to do bundle install, but says could not locate Gemfile, how do I fix this?

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-20.04, canvas-lms

canvas-lms on ubuntu 20.04. Trying to do bundle install, but says could not locate Gemfile, how do I fix this? Please help me :(

Im trying to download canvas-lms on ubuntu 20.04 but there is not enough information out there. Does anyone have a full guide?

Comment: monday left me broken...